# How do you see Tx/Rx Bus data in trace window via the COM interface in CANalyzer in C++?

Tags: c++, com, can-bus, canoe, canalyzer

I am completely new to this topic and I've been asked to create an application that shows the data exchange happening on a bus in CANalyzer via the COM interface, with the exact virtual time point when that data is being sent.

So far, what I have is this :

```
// DemoTool.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//


#include "DemoTool.h"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "CANalyzer.h"
#include "comdef.h"



class VApplication
{
public:
    VApplication() : mApplication(NULL) {}
    ~VApplication() {}
    bool Connect();
    bool StartMeasurement(int timeOut=5); // seconds
    bool SendData();
    bool StopMeasurement();
    void ShutDown();
private:
    CComPtr<IApplication> mApplication;
    CComPtr<IMeasurement5> mMeasurement;
    CComPtr<IConfiguration14> mConfiguration;
    CComPtr<IBus3> mBus;
};

bool VApplication::Connect()
{

    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    if (mApplication != NULL) return true;

    CLSID clsId;
    hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"CANalyzer.Application", &clsId);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = CoCreateInstance(clsId, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER, __uuidof(IApplication10), (void**)&mApplication);
            
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                CComPtr<IDispatch> dispatchMeasurement;
                hr = mApplication->get_Measurement(&dispatchMeasurement);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    std::cout << "Failed to get measurement pointer.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    hr = dispatchMeasurement->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMeasurement5), (void**)&mMeasurement);
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        std::cout << "Failed to dispatch measurement pointer.\n";
                    }
                }


                CComPtr<IDispatch> dispatchConfiguration;
                hr = mApplication->get_Configuration(&dispatchConfiguration);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    std::cout << "Failed to get Configuration pointer.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    hr = dispatchConfiguration->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IConfiguration14), (void**)&mConfiguration);
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        std::cout << "Failed to dispatch Configuration pointer.\n";
                    }
                }
                CComPtr<IDispatch> dispatchBus;
                hr = mApplication->get_Bus(L"CAN", &dispatchBus);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    std::cout << "Failed to get Bus pointer.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    hr = dispatchBus->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IBus3), (void**)&mBus);
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        std::cout << "Failed to dispatch Bus pointer.\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}

bool VApplication::StartMeasurement(int timeOut)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0x0;
    int attempt = 0;
    VARIANT_BOOL toolIsRun = 0;

    hr = mMeasurement->Start();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        while (toolIsRun != -1)
        {
            attempt++;
            Sleep(1);
            hr = mMeasurement->get_Running(&toolIsRun);
            if (attempt > timeOut) break;
        };
        if (toolIsRun == -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}

bool VApplication::SendData()
{
    CComPtr<IMessage2> msg;
}

bool VApplication::StopMeasurement()
{
    HRESULT hr = 0x0;
    int attempt = 0;
    VARIANT_BOOL toolIsRunning = 0;

    hr = mMeasurement->StopEx();
    Sleep(100);
    hr = mMeasurement->get_Running(&toolIsRunning);
    if (toolIsRunning == -1)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        hr = mMeasurement->get_Running(&toolIsRunning);

        if (toolIsRunning == -1)
        {
            hr = mMeasurement->StopEx();
            Sleep(100);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "CANalyzer is stopped.\n";
        }

        hr = mMeasurement->get_Running(&toolIsRunning);
        if (toolIsRunning)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to get status from CANalyzer. Tool may still be running!\n";
        }
    }
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}

void VApplication::ShutDown()
{
    if (mMeasurement)
    {
        mMeasurement.Release();
    }
    if (mApplication)
    {
        mApplication.Release();
    }
}

static CComModule module;
static VApplication* app;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello CMake." << std::endl;
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    module.Init(NULL, ::GetModuleHandle(NULL));

    app = new VApplication();
    bool conval = app->Connect();
    std::cout << "Connection " << (conval ? "established.\n" : "not established.\n");
    bool mesval = app->StartMeasurement();
    std::cout << "Measurement " << (mesval ? "started.\n" : "not started.\n");
    int wait;
    std::cin >> wait; // just to verify manually that the connection has started
    bool stoval = app->StopMeasurement();
    std::cout << "Measurement " << (stoval ? "stopped.\n" : "not stopped.\n");
    app->ShutDown();
    delete app;
    app = nullptr;
    module.Term();
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

But I cannot figure out a single way in which I can see the data inside the tool itself. I thought maybe it would be variables but no, they are system variables and not meant for network signals at all. I thought maybe via Channel object I could make the tool tap into the data but turns out the Channel component interface is not available in CANalyzer - it is meant for transmission of data into CANoe.

Also, I can't find a way to increment the simulation time in the tool as well, because the simulation pointer is not available.

Is there any way in which the above two points can be handled?

My end goal is to watch the Tx and Rx data exchanged between two nodes on a bus getting listed in the trace window of CANalyzer(like CANoe).

Comment: The product is called CAN*alyzer* because it is used for *analyzing* the bus communication. If you want the send data over the busses (which I assume you want to do, according to your description), you have to use CANoe.

Comment: @MSpiller thank you for your comment. I should've worded my question better. I understand that CANalyzer is supposed to just tap into the data. But question is, how do I programmatically do that? Which interface component do I use?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You ask about how to send data from C++ to CANalyzer. Your comment now states the opposite. Feel free to edit the question (or create a new one) and describe your usecase.

Comment: @MSpiller I have edited the question now. Please let me know if it is a bit more clear. Since I'm completely new to this topic, my understanding is messed up. I was under the impression that to make CANalyzer tap into the data exchange happening on a bus, I need to manually send the bus data to the tool (rather than the tool detect it by itself).

Comment: Good CAN analyzers/listeners log timing parameters, so it should just be a matter of tapping into the right column of the tool's log. As for how to do that, I don't know since I have no up to date experience of using the Vector tool chain/API.

Comment: Still confused... _My end goal is to watch the Tx and Rx data exchanged between two nodes on a bus getting listed in the trace window of CANalyzer(like CANoe)._ That is the sole purpose of CANalyzer. You create a configuration, attach to the bus and can directly observe the communication. How does the COM-Interface come into play? What do you want to do using COM? Building the CANalyzer configuration? Do you want to _re-implement_ the trace window in your own tool using COM?

Comment: @MSpiller the bus is a virtual bus. So I am not using any hardware bus for communication. This attaching to the bus needs to happen (from what I understand) via the COM interface.

Comment: Would be good if all details could be found in the question... The virtual bus acts the same ways as a hardware bus except that it is _virtual_. In your CANalyzer configuration (Channel Mapping) you then select the virtual bus instead of a hardware interface. Which nodes do you have attached to the virtual bus? Still don't know what your use case is.